# Quicktabs: output divs instead of list

Tags: 7, theming, blocks

I am quite new to theming, and I am trying to figure out the right way of theming Quicktabs in D7. I would like to output the tabs as divs instead of as a `<ul>` list. Looking at info from Theme Developer tells me that the Quicktabs are defined by `qt_quicktabs_tabset` which in turn calls `theme_item_list()` .

I could override `theme_item_list()` in my `template.php` file, but it would require a lot of tweaking because the `theme_item_list()` is designed for outputting a list. So for the moment my approach is to make a new theme function available in a custom module  like this

```
function mymodule_theme() {
  return array(
    'mymodule_hook' => array(
      'variables' => array ('parameter' => NULL),
    ),
  );
}

function theme_mymodule_hook($variables){
  //here I can output my tabs as divs
}
```

and calling this in this way in `template.php`:

```
/**
 * Theme function to output tablinks for classic Quicktabs style tabs.
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
function mytheme_qt_quicktabs_tabset(&$vars) {
  $variables = array(
    'attributes' => array(
      'class' => 'quicktabs-tabs quicktabs-style-' . $vars['tabset']['#options']['style'],
    ),
    'items' => array(),
  );
  foreach (element_children($vars['tabset']['tablinks']) as $key) {
    $item = array();
    if (is_array($vars['tabset']['tablinks'][$key])) {
      $tab = $vars['tabset']['tablinks'][$key];
      if ($key == $vars['tabset']['#options']['active']) {
        $item['class'] = array('active');
      }
      $item['data'] = drupal_render($tab);
      $variables['items'][] = $item;
    }
  }
  //normally theme_item_list() is called: return theme('item_list', $variables);
  return theme('mymoduletabs_hook', $variables);
}

function mytheme_mymoduletabs_hook($variables){
  //here I can finally output my tabs in divs
}
```

It's the first time I try this approach and would appreciate feedback. The intricacy of my solution worries me a bit - am I on the right path here?

Comment: Why not just give the quicktabs a layout i.e. `display: block` and simply theme them as if they were divs. I think it would also help to know what exactly you are trying to do. It may also be possible to do this with a few lines of JQuery if you truly want to convert them.

Comment: The layout I was trying to implement included clickable images as part of the markup. I have looked more into solving the issue with jQuery and css only - definitely the way to go. I have added the jQuery code below.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery seems to be the way to go if you want to manipulate the markup output by Quicktabs.

```
 /*we only want to append the data once hence the condition */
 if (!($('#quicktabs-my_tabs .quicktabs-tabs li img').length > 0)) {
   $('#quicktabs-my_tabs .quicktabs-tabs li.first').prepend("<img src='sites/all/themes/mytheme/images/my_img1.jpg' alt='desc'>");
   $('#quicktabs-my_tabs .quicktabs-tabs li.first').next().prepend("<img src='sites/all/themes/mytheme/images/my_img2.jpg' alt='desc'>");
   $('#quicktabs-my_tabs .quicktabs-tabs li.last').prepend("<img src='sites/all/themes/mytheme/images/my_img3.jpg' alt='desc'>");
   $('#quicktabs-my_tabs .quicktabs-tabs li a').append('<span></span>');
 }
```

Note that this example works for 3 tabs - it should be modified for your setup.

In order to make the whole quicktab a clickable link, add appropriate css to the `span` inside the `a` element, as described in this post: [Make a div into a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796087/make-a-div-into-a-link)

Comment: If all you are trying to do is add images for tabs, Quicktabs already has themes / settings / provisions for that. Did you have a look at how that's done natively in Quicktabs? Typically what I do is choose "no Style" on the configuration page and then grab some existing code from the module's CSS and add it to my own theme. Quciktabs for Drupal 7 can even use JQuery UI I think.

Comment: Yes, I tried to make my own Quicktab style, but I couldn't accomplish the layout I wanted that way - that might be my lack of skills, I don't know. Thanks for your advice anyways.